# Superset & DECK.GL -- cannot display shaded polygons

Tags: gis, apache-superset, deck.gl

I want to visualize Zip3 polygons, shaded by the population.  I have GeoJSON formatted as text strings in a Snowflake table, and am able to visualize them using the "Deck.GL GEOJSON" map type, but not "Deck.GL Polygon", which is what I need.

I have tested the GeoJSON with geojson.io and they are valid.

This is a "Deck.GL Polygon" type and does not work (showing up blank, but with the Legend correctly displaying):

[image]

This is a "Deck.GL GEOJSON" type and which DOES work (but does not allow me to color it by population):

[image]

Any ideas how to shade these polygons in Superset?

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need `PolygonLayer` instead of `GeoJsonLayer`? At the end `GeoJsonLayer` renders a `SolidPolygonLayer`

So, `GeoJsonLayer` = `SolidPolygonLayer`

One of the differences between rendering a `GeoJsonLayer` or `SolidPolygonLayer` is that, if your data is already a geojson format, you don't need to specify an accessor to tell deck.gl where your data coordinates are located (because internally interprets where those are => `feature => geometry => coordinates`)

I would go using a `GeoJsonLayer`, and then, for styling polygons, you will need to use `getFillColor` accessor like:

```js
new GeoJsonLayer({
  ...,
  getFillColor: ({ properties }) => {
    if (properties.population > 1_000_000) {
       return [255, 0, 0]
    }
    return [0, 255, 0]
  }
})
```